# VSCode "trigger suggest" won't open with the focus at the top

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, typing

When I trigger the command "trigger suggest" while in the editor, I would expect the scrollbar to be at the top. That would be helpful because I am using a lot of typescript interfaces in my program and I'd like to pick the possible values directly on suggestion. But when I invoke the command, the scrollbar is placed in the middle and suggest something I obviously don't care of.

[image]

Is it an issue, am I doing something wrong ? If not, is there a way to change this... annoying situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try :

> // Controls how suggestions are pre-selected when showing the suggest
>   list.

```
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
```